# C++1z handling of a == test with std::initializer_list<int> with and w/o const in an auto function

Tags: c++, auto, c++14, initializer-list, c++17

`c_NEXT` is defined in `class AskBase`:

```
struct Status {
    static auto constexpr   c_ROOT      {-999};
    static auto constexpr   c_PREVIOUS  {-1};
    static auto constexpr   c_NEXT      {1};
    static auto constexpr   c_EOF       {999};
};
```

Later `c_NEXT` is used in `template<typename Container> class AskUI`

```
auto run(){
    auto status = AskBase::Status::c_NEXT;
    for (typename Container::iterator ii=m_asks.begin();
            ii!=m_asks.end();
            ii=(AskBase::Status::c_ROOT==status)? m_asks.begin():
                (AskBase::Status::c_PREVIOUS==status)?(m_asks.begin()==ii?m_asks.begin():ii-1):
                (AskBase::Status::c_NEXT==status)?ii+1:
                m_asks.end())
        status = (*ii)->ask_user();
    return (AskBase::Status::c_NEXT==status);
}
```

Referring to the three `()?` expressions and the `return` statement clang++ reports:

```
error: invalid operands to binary expression ('const std::initializer_list<int>'
and 'std::initializer_list<int>')
```

Suggestions on resolving the error.

Using command:

```
clang++ -std=c++1z
```

Comment: My suggestion to resolve this would be to replace the constants with an enum

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the [adoption](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n4251.html#CWG16) of [N3922](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n3922.html) at the November 2014 committee meeting, the four initializations in the question will now deduce `int` rather than `initializer_list<int>`. The paper makes `auto` used in the *direct-list-initialization* context (i.e., `auto x{/*...*/};`) ill-formed unless the list contains only one element, in which case the type is deduced directly from that element. *copy-list-initialization* - `auto x = {/*...*/};` - remains unchanged and will deduce a `std::initializer_list`.

Quoting from the examples added to the standard in that paper:

```
auto x3{ 1, 2 }; // error: not a single element
auto x4 = { 3 }; // decltype(x4) is std::initializer_list<int>
auto x5{ 3 }; // decltype(x5) is int
```

Since the paper says

> Direction from EWG is that we consider this a defect in C++14.

and compiler implementers usually apply defect reports retroactively, we might see this implemented in the C++11/14 modes of compilers, in addition to the C++1z(17?) mode.

Answer (score 1):

[Effective Modern C++](http://cdn.oreillystatic.com/oreilly/booksamplers/9781491903995_sampler.pdf) page 23:

> in C++11 programming is accidentally declaring a
>   std::initializer_list
>   variable
>   when you mean to declare something else. This pitfall is one of the reasons some
>   developers put braces around their initializers only when they have to.

```
struct Status {
    static auto constexpr   c_ROOT      =-999;
    static auto constexpr   c_PREVIOUS  =  -1;
    static auto constexpr   c_NEXT      =   1;
    static auto constexpr   c_EOF       = 999;
};
```

Comment: There's a proposal [N3922](http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/papers/2014/n3922.html) to change it so that `auto` deduces `{n}` to the type of `n` (i.e. a special case for lists of length 1), however debate is raging strong and the proposal may not be accepted

Comment: The base rationale for `auto` deducing to `initializer_list` is to allow `auto a = { 1,2,3 }; func1(a); func2(a);` and it's heavily debatable whether or not a list of length 1 should give a special case here.

Comment: @MattMcNabb It's been adopted at the last meeting, see [the minutes, CWG motion 16](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n4251.html#CWG16).

Comment: @TC if nothing else I guess it provides a bunch more corner cases for us to gain SO karma by answering questions from puzzled posters like this one...:)